# Filtering observations based on specific date condition using data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a set of observations, which are recorded every time a user has taken an action. I want to filter only those observations from a user which are six or more months apart.

So, if a user has taken this action on "2018-01-01", "2018-03-01" and "2018-07-01", I only want to keep only "2018-01-01" and "2018-07-01".

Similarly, if a user has taken an action on "2018-01-01", "2018-03-01", "2018-07-01" and "2019-03-01" I want to keep only "2018-01-01", "2018-07-01", "2019-03-01".

So far, I have produced long and unworkable code.

```r
# What I want to achieve
library(data.table)

dataIhave <- data.table(id    = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4), 
                        dates = c("2018-01-01", 
                                  "2018-03-01",
                                  "2018-07-01",
                                  "2019-01-01",
                                  "2018-01-03", 
                                  "2018-07-02", 
                                  "2018-02-01",
                                  "2018-02-01"))

dataIwant <- data.table(id    = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                        dates = c("2018-01-01", 
                                  "2018-07-01",
                                  "2019-01-01",
                                  "2018-01-01", 
                                  "2018-02-01",
                                  "2018-02-01"))
```

Comment: for id=2, do you mean 2018-01-03 instead of 2018-01-01?

Answer (score 6):

This is a rolling-join variant of @Uwe's answer:

```
library(lubridate)
dataIhave[, dates := as.IDate(dates)]

ids = unique(dataIhave$id)

dataIhave[, seq := NA_integer_]
s = 1L
w = dataIhave[.(ids), on=.(id), mult="first", which = TRUE]
dataIhave[w, seq := s]
while (TRUE){
  w = dataIhave[
    dataIhave[w, .(id, dates = dates %m+% months(6))], 
    on = .(id, dates), roll = -Inf, nomatch = 0, which = TRUE
  ]

  if (!length(w)) break
  s = s + 1L
  dataIhave[w, seq := s]
}

dataIhave[!is.na(seq)]

   id      dates seq
1:  1 2018-01-01   1
2:  1 2018-07-01   2
3:  1 2019-01-01   3
4:  2 2018-01-03   1
5:  3 2018-02-01   1
6:  4 2018-02-01   1
```

The loop takes rows `w` defined per `id`, steps their `dates` forward six months, and takes the next row found, if any. The arguments to the join are:

- The tables, with join syntax `x[i, ...]`

  - `x = dataIhave`
  - `i = dataIhave[w, .(id, dates = dates %m+% months(6))]`
- `on = .(id, date)`: columns to match by
- `roll = -Inf`: find the next match on the last column in `on=`
- `nomatch = 0`: if no match is found, skip
- `which = TRUE`: return matched row number

Additionally, if there are duplicate dates (see the second example in @Uwe's post):

- `mult = "first"`: take only the first match for each row of `i`

In selecting the first row by `id` before the loop, I'm assuming the data is sorted by `dates` within `id` (so I'm not using `order` as @Uwe's answer does).

Comment: Thank you for the recursive rolling join version. However, in order to deal with duplicate dates as in my 2nd test case, the rolling join requires the `mult="first"` parameter as well.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to drop those dates which are less than six months apart from the beginning of a period and start a new period at the first date that is more than 6 months apart from the begin of the previous period (separately for each `id`).

I have no idea how this can be accomplished by a *non-recursive* rolling or non-equi join as there is no fixed grid of dates. So, I believe it requires a kind of recursive approach, somehow. Here is one possibility:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
dataIhave[, dates := as.Date(dates)]
dataIhave[, keep := TRUE]
dataIhave[order(id, dates)
  , keep := {
    start <- dates[1L]
    for (i in tail(seq_along(dates), -1L)) {
      if (dates[i] < start %m+% months(6)) {
        keep[i] <- FALSE
      } else {
        start <- dates[i]
      }
    }
    keep
  }, by = id][]
```

> ```
>    id      dates  keep
> 1:  1 2018-01-01  TRUE
> 2:  1 2018-03-01 FALSE
> 3:  1 2018-07-01  TRUE
> 4:  1 2019-01-01  TRUE
> 5:  2 2018-01-03  TRUE
> 6:  2 2018-07-02 FALSE
> 7:  3 2018-02-01  TRUE
> 8:  4 2018-02-01  TRUE
> ```

Finally,

```
dataIhave[(keep), -"keep"]
```

> ```
>    id      dates
> 1:  1 2018-01-01
> 2:  1 2018-07-01
> 3:  1 2019-01-01
> 4:  2 2018-01-03
> 5:  3 2018-02-01
> 6:  4 2018-02-01
> ```

#### 2nd test case

The crucial point here is to detect the beginning of a new period (within each `id`).

As an additional test case I have added two dates to `id == 1`,
`2018-07-01` and `2018-07-02`.
`2018-07-01` is a duplicate. Both dates should be removed as they lie within the second 6-months period starting at `2018-07-01`.

```
dataIhave <- fread("
 id      dates
  1 2018-01-01
  1 2018-03-01
  1 2018-07-01
  1 2018-07-01
  1 2018-07-02
  1 2019-01-01
  2 2018-01-03
  2 2018-07-02
  3 2018-02-01
  4 2018-02-01")
```

Indeed, the code above returns the same output as with OP's original test case.

#### Remove rows only within the *first* six months for each `id`

*If* the question is interpreted to only remove entries within the *first* 6-months period for each `id` and keep all the date after 6 months this can be achieved by

```
dataIhave[!dataIhave[, .I[dates < dates[1L] %m+% months(6L)][-1L], by = id]$V1]
```

which returns

> ```
>    id      dates
> 1:  1 2018-01-01
> 2:  1 2018-07-01
> 3:  1 2018-07-01
> 4:  1 2018-07-02
> 5:  1 2019-01-01
> 6:  2 2018-01-03
> 7:  3 2018-02-01
> 8:  4 2018-02-01
> ```

for the second test case. (Note that this is a streamlined version of [Jaap's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56713353/3817004).)

Answer (score 2):

Another variant:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

dataIhave[, dates := as.Date(dates)]

dataIhave[, keep := dates >= dates[1] %m+% months(6), by = id
          ][dataIhave[, .I[1], by = id][[2]], keep := TRUE
            ][!!keep, -"keep"]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id      dates
> 1:  1 2018-01-01
> 2:  1 2018-07-01
> 3:  1 2019-01-01
> 4:  2 2018-01-03
> 5:  3 2018-02-01
> 6:  4 2018-02-01
> ```

Comment: Your answer removes only dates within the _first_ 6 months for each `id`. So, your code gives a different result for my 2nd test case. (I don't say this is wrong as it depends on the interpretation of the Q.)

Comment: @Uwe I know, as you already noted: it's just another (simpler) interpretation of the question

Comment: Congrats with a `data.table` badge :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using non-equi join and `igraph` to avoid implicit loops and recursion:

```
#data prep
dataIhave[, dates := as.IDate(dates, format="%Y-%m-%d")]
setorder(dataIhave[, rn:=rowid(id)], id, dates)
dataIhave[, end := as.IDate(sapply(dates, 
    function(d) seq(d, by="6 months", length.out=2L)[2L]))]

#non-equi self join to find first date that is after 6months
nonequi <- dataIhave[dataIhave, on=.(id, dates>=end), mult="first", by=.EACHI,
    .(i.id, i.rn, x.rn, i.dates, x.dates)]

library(igraph)
nonequi[, {
        #create graph from the previous join
        g <- graph_from_data_frame(.SD[, .(i.rn, x.rn)])
        #plot(g)

        #find the leaf nodes
        leaf <- sapply(V(g), function(x) length(neighbors(g,x))==0L)

        #from the first date (i.e. node = V(g)["1"]), find the path starting from this date.
        path <- get.all.shortest.paths(g, V(g)["1"], leaf)$res

        #return all dates (i.e. nodes) in this path
        .(dates=i.dates[i.rn %in% na.omit(V(g)[path[[1L]]]$name)])
    },
    by=.(id=i.id)]
```

output:

```
   id      dates
1:  1 2018-01-01
2:  1 2018-07-01
3:  1 2019-01-01
4:  2 2018-01-03
5:  3 2018-02-01
6:  4 2018-02-01
```

---

Or a recursive approach similar to Uwe's solution:

```
dataIhave[, dates := as.IDate(dates, format="%Y-%m-%d")]
unique(dataIhave[,
    .(dates=as.IDate(Reduce(
        function(x, y) if (y >= seq(x, by="6 months", length.out=2L)[2L]) y else x,
        dates,
        accumulate=TRUE))),
    .(id)])
```

output:

```
   id      dates
1:  1 2018-01-01
2:  1 2018-07-01
3:  1 2019-01-01
4:  2 2018-01-03
5:  3 2018-02-01
6:  4 2018-02-01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

dataiHave[, dates := ymd(dates)]
dataiHave[, difDates := as.numeric(difftime(dates, units = "weeks"))]

dataIHave[difDates >= 24, .(id, dates)]
```

Does this produce the result you want?

Months have irregular durations so you'll have to stick to a time unit of fixed duration.

You can also check `?lubridate::interval`, `lubridate::as. duration` and this question: [Time difference in years with lubridate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312925/time-difference-in-years-with-lubridate)

Comment: I guess you can compare the date vs the date plus six months: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22646010 However, OP's rules might be underspecified. With events at months 1, 4, 8, 12, a valid "at least six months apart" selection could be (1, 8), (1, 12), (4, 12) and it's not clear which should be preferred.

Comment: @Frank I believe the OP wants to drop those dates which are less than six months apart from the beginning of a period and start a new period at the first date that is more than 6 months apart from the begin of the previous period.