# How to control the unit of a time difference in R?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I calculate some durations in R as shown below. Depending of the value of the duration, the unit can be minutes, hours, days, etc.:

```
library(lubridate)
start <- "2022-08-27 10:06:58"
end <- "2022-08-27 10:10:24"
start <- as_datetime(start)
end   <- as_datetime(end)
end - start
# Time difference of 3.433333 mins
start - Sys.time()
# Time difference of -3.136468 days
```

I want to always get the durations in minutes, how could I achieve that?

Comment: `difftime(start, Sys.time(), units = "mins")`.

Comment: `as.numeric(end - start, unit = "mins")`

Comment: Nice, Gabor.  That is one step smaller than what I used for decades, namely converting after `difftime()`.  But the S3 dispatch gives us `difftime()` anyway so there is the use of `unit` argument.  Noted, and will try to remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `lubridate` but you likely want an argument to `difftime()`:

##### Code

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2022-08-27 10:06:58")
end <- as.POSIXct("2022-08-27 10:10:24")
difftime(end, start, unit="mins")
```

##### Output

```
> start <- as.POSIXct("2022-08-27 10:06:58")
> end <- as.POSIXct("2022-08-27 10:10:24")
> difftime(end, start, unit="mins")
Time difference of 3.43333 mins
>
```

And yup, likely a duplicate a few times over.

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312925/time-difference-in-years-with-lubridate) is easy to adapt to minutes.

Comment: It's all just plain subtraction and scaling so I never used anything but base R for this.  One _can_ use `lubridate` and many users find it appealing, but as I said one does not _need_ it as the basic operations are all available in base R.

Comment: No, it wasn't me. And I didn't close because it is not an exact duplicate and you'll never know what "easy" to adapt means to others.

Comment: Oh but additional context is that Stephane and I "know" each other I know how lingual and knowledgeable he is.